# Satellizer and Facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, satellizer

I'm using rails and angular to build an app. I'm using satellizer to login in the app.

Here is my devise configuration:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "xxx1", "secret", :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
```

On JS side:

```
$authProvider.loginUrl = '/users/sign_in';
  $authProvider.facebook({clientId: 'xxx1', url: '/users/auth/facebook', type: '2.0'});
```

When i choose login with fb a popup appears, then i authenticate, and finaly when the popup is close i got this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=804…allback&state=c2131db90c6208181da224094bc2043ac43be5507bc2be8a&scope=email. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You may turn it off credentials flag by setting

```
$authProvider.withCredentials = false;
```

More details:
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/releases/tag/0.9.1